# Реализация выбора dim, normal, bright colorama

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Попытался реализовать способ выбора методов (DIM, NORMAL, BRIGHT) из класса Style.

Тот в свою очередь из пакета colorama.

Но однако Style подчёркивается красным.

Ошибка:
`[pylint] E1102:Style.(DIM/NORMAL/BRIGHT) is not callable`

Код:

```
if type == "dim":
   Style.DIM()
elif type == "normal":
   Style.NORMAL()
elif type == "bright":
   Style.BRIGHT()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по ошибке `E1102:Style.(DIM/NORMAL/BRIGHT) is not callable` элементы `DIM/NORMAL/BRIGHT` не являются функциями и у них нет метода `__call__`, поэтому скобки `()` не нужны.

Если посмотреть в [примере colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), то видно, что элементы из `Style` используются без `()`:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```